# Limit Selectable DOM Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, checkbox

I am trying to limit the number of checkboxes a user can select.  These checkboxes are DOM input objects generated for each item in an array.  I'm having no luck with this currently, so any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/vVxM2/222/

```
names =["Donny","Danny","Ricky","Eric","Jamie","Bobby","Booby"];
var numberOf = names.length; 
var text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < numberOf; i++) {
    text += "<li class='playerListItem'><label><input type='checkbox' class='playerCheckbox'>" + names[i] + "</label></li>";
    }
text += "</ul>";
document.getElementById("recentPlayersContainer").innerHTML = text;


var limit = 3;
$('input.playerCheckbox').on('change', function(event) {
if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
   this.checked = false;
}
});
```

Comment: I think it's because your checkboxes are not siblings because they are nested further in `li` and `label` elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in the `change` event.

Instead of doing:

```
if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit)
```

You should do this:

```
if($('.playerCheckbox:checked').length >= limit)
```

Also, if your limit is maximum 3 checked, then you should do:

```
$('.playerCheckbox:checked').length > limit
```

Because when the event `change` is raised, the current checkbox is already checked.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem was found here: `if($(this).parent().siblings().children(":checkbox:checked").length >= limit)`.  You actually have two parents, so you should have added another `parent()` and `children()` function.  It should look like `if($(this).parent().parent().siblings().children().children(":checkbox:checked").length >= limit)`

```js
names = ["Donny", "Danny", "Ricky", "Eric", "Jamie", "Bobby", "Booby"];
var numberOf = names.length;
var text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < numberOf; i++) {
  text += "<li class='playerListItem'><label><input type='checkbox' class='playerCheckbox'>" + names[i] + "</label></li>";
}
text += "</ul>";
document.getElementById("recentPlayersContainer").innerHTML = text;


var limit = 3;
$('input.playerCheckbox').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).parent().parent().siblings().children().children(":checkbox:checked").length >= limit) {
    $(this).attr('checked', false);
    alert('You can only select 3 checkboxes.');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="recentPlayersContainer">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vVxM2/231/)

```
 names =["Donny","Danny","Ricky","Eric","Jamie","Bobby","Booby"];
        var numberOf = names.length; 
        var text = "<ul>";
        for (i = 0; i < numberOf; i++) {
            text += "<li class='playerListItem'><label><input type='checkbox' class='playerCheckbox'>" + names[i] + "</label></li>";
            }
        text += "</ul>";
        document.getElementById("recentPlayersContainer").innerHTML = text;


    var limit = 3;
    $('input.playerCheckbox').on('change', function(event) {
            if($('input.playerCheckbox:checked').length >= limit + 1) {
              alert('enough');
            }
    });
```

Comment: Pretty close. You ommited that when 'change' event was raised the checkbox state was already changed. So it will be counted.