# Set limit for checked value in list box

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have multiple select listbox, i want to restrict the user when he selects more than 3 values. The values can be country or cities, they are coming from database. The code for same is written in `lstArea_SelectedIndexChanged` method.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstArea" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lstArea_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:ListBox>
```

I found jquery code to validate the same, but the change function is not working.

```
    var limit = 3;
    $("#<%=lstArea.ClientID%>").change(function () {
        if ($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
            this.checked = false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: "above 3 values" which are not included in your question. Please finish your question before submitting it.

Comment: "the change function is not working." Is the if statement not returning what you're expecting? Or if this.checked not doing what you expect?

Comment: @KSib when i debug this, the control doesnt go inside the function

Comment: @Thomas I have edited the question.

Comment: Did you look at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think this address can help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27490795/5631805
Maybe you should instead of

```
 if ($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit)
```

this

```
if($('#lstArea:checked').length >= limit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have set the property `AutoPostBack` to `true`, and you have also set the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event handler, .NET will generate `onchange` attribute for your select which will trigger POST back to the server, whenever an item will be selected. To prevent that you need to change your .NET code to this:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstArea" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"/>
```

and also update your javascript code to this:

```
// Handle for the list
var list = $("#<%=lstArea.ClientID%>");

// Our limit
var limit = 3;

// Get currently selected values
var selected = list.val();

// Handle change event
list.change(function () {
    // If we reached the limit
    if (list.find(":checked").length >= limit) {
        // Set the list value back to the previous ones
        list.val(selected);
        return;
    }

    // Postback to the server
    setTimeout("__doPostBack('<%=lstArea.ClientID%>','')", 0);
});
```

Each time the page will be rendered the `selected` variable will hold the last selected items. Than in the `change` handler you will get all the selected/checked options, and when the count of the newly selected options is more than or equal to your limit you will unselect the last selected value by setting back all previous values. And if the limit is ok, you will made your postback, by calling the .NET function `__doPostBack`.